API method only works locally
I have a method in the API controller which allows you to add numbers, it works correctly when I test with a simulator and start the API locally, however the published API when I test with it I receive a 404 error not found (the login user id and the numbers being the same)
 [HttpPut("UpdateSOSNumber/{userId}/{numbers}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateSOSNumber(int userId, string numbers)
 {
     UsersEntity user = await _usersRepository.FindByIdAsync(userId);

     if (user != null)
     {
         user.SOSNumber += (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.SOSNumber) ? "" : ",") + numbers;

         await _usersRepository.UpdateAsync(user);
         await _usersRepository.SaveAsync();

         return Ok("SOS numbers updated successfully");
     }
     else
         return NotFound("User not found");
 }


  private async Task UpdateSOSNumber(string numbers)
  {
      int loginUserId = Convert.ToInt32(await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.UserId));

      using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
      {
          httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);
          var requestUri = $"api/v1/Users/UpdateSOSNumber/{loginUserId}/{numbers}";
          var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(requestUri, null);
      }
  }



Error 404 means you have a Role issue where user is not authorized to access the Route.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0.  It works locally so the route exists provided all the files in project got installed on the server.

I didn't understand exactly what to do (I specify that I have other methods which retrieve the user with the user id and it works)

Do you have [Authorize] in the controller code?  If so remove.  Check files in the bin folder locally for executable file.  Then see what files also exist in same folder.  Make sure all these files are in the same folder on the deploy machine.

I didn't add authorize null anywhere and as I said I have other methods that call the user id which work

Do they call numbers?  Did you check the files?  Where is the code for numbers?

exemple in requesturi : "api/v1/Users/UpdateSOSNumber/171/+33782180741"

Are the version of libraries you are using the same locally and remote?  How can you divide by a string?  The variable {numbers} is a string.  What may be happening is the number is being converted to a string and on two different machine the results is slightly different.  You are dividing by 33782180741 and the fractional results may be slightly different. on two different machines.

In local, on the same computer I open 2 visual studio, I launch the API and the simulator

@ChrisCurt Is AppSettings.UrlApi configured correctly on the server where you have deployed your API?

The error indicates the route {numbers} is wrong.  Your number 33782180741 is larger than 32 bits, but you are using ToInt32 to convert.  This may give a different answer on two different machines.

I do not convert the number to Int32, but the user Id, and I have always done that without problem...
